# Javascript new Date() give me the same result when executing getTime()

Tags: javascript, date, gettime

To compage 2 date i'm doing a conversion from a string to the javascript Date object.

This is an exemple of the code i have:

```
 var date1 = new Date(dateArrray1[2], dateArrray1[1], dateArrray1[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);
 var date2 = new Date(dateArrray2[2], dateArrray2[1], dateArrray2[0], 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

My issu is on the fact that when i'm doing a validation on those 2 date object I got the same result on the getTime function for a certain date.

```
var date1 = new Date(2012, 01, 30, 12, 0, 0, 0).getTime()
var date2 = new Date(2012, 02, 01, 12, 0, 0, 0).getTime()
```

Normally the value of `date1` dans `date2` should be different. But surprise! The value of those 2 object are the same (actually the value is `1330621200000`).

Do someone got the same issue as me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript dates use 0-based months.
If you pass an invalid date, such as February 30<sup>th</sup>, it will figure out what that date actually is.
Thus, February 30<sup>th</sup> of a leap year is the same as March 1<sup>st</sup>.

Comment: This is true only because it's a leap year. Ordinarily Feb 30 is Mar 2.

Comment: You mean that if I parse my pass value to the constructor, then I do -1 on it, my date will give me the good value ?

Answer (score 3):

The month field has the range 0 - 11, not 1 - 12

So in this case you've asked for the 30th of February and the 1st of March.

This year February has 29 days, so the 30th of Feb is (mathematically) the same as the 1st of March.